# How to define a global Array of string on web page level

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, global-variables

I defined a global array of `String` and I use it in on click event for 2 buttons.

```
Dim arrPoliciesNumber() As String = New String() {}
```

and in first button click event i inserted the values in the array

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
 If MultipleData.Value <> "" Then

        Dim _Data = MultipleData.Value.Split(vbLf)
        arrPoliciesNumber = MultipleData.Value.Split(vbLf)
        For Each _Text In _Data

            _SearchList1Value = _SearchList1Value + _Text.Trim + "','"

        Next
        _SearchList1Value = Left(_SearchList1Value, _SearchList1Value.Length - 3)

        _SearchList1Value = "'" + _SearchList1Value + "'"

    Else
        If txtSearch1.Text.Trim <> "" Then
            _SearchList1Value = txtSearch1.Text
            arrPoliciesNumber = New String(0) {}
            arrPoliciesNumber(0) = New String(txtSearch1.Text)
            _SearchList1Value = "'" + _SearchList1Value + "'"
        End If

    End If
```

now on another button click event i tried to get the inserted string in the array but i found it empty with Length = 0

```
 If arrPoliciesNumber.Length > 0 Then
        'here we need to add the report parameter with report ID

        For Each policyNo As String In arrPoliciesNumber
            _DB.AddReportRequestParameter(reportId, policyNo)
        Next

    End If
```

how i can keep the inserted values in the array ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to [keep state on post back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is an object that gets instantiated on each request (each button click). This means that you are creating a new array with each button click. Have a look at this [caching](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334277/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Caching-in-ASP-NET) tutorial for a few ideas on how to preserve your data.